# <c:when test="${action == view}"> never evaluates true on URL with ?action=view

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have the following code:

```
<%@ page language="java" session="true" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<% 
request.setAttribute("action", request.getParameter("action"));
%>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${action == null}">
        NULL
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${action == view}">
        VIEW
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

However when I pass URL with `?action=view`, it doesn't show `VIEW`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EL expression `${view}` is looking for an attribute on exactly that name in page, request, session or application scope like as how `${action}` works. However, you intented to compare it to a string. You should then use quotes to make it a true string variable like so `${'view'}`. It also works that way in normal Java code.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${action == null}">
        NULL
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${action == 'view'}">
        VIEW
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

By the way, copying a request parameter as a request attribute using that *scriptlet* is clumsy. [You should not be using *scriptlets* at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202). HTTP request parameters are in EL already available by the `${param}` map.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${param.action == null}">
        NULL
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${param.action == 'view'}">
        VIEW
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

This way you can get rid of the whole `<% .. %>` line.

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: +1 Small note: I would use empty operator instead of null comparsion